# Add rules when creating a POJO

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using lombok's annotation [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) when writing pojos because it automatically generates constructor, hashCode as well as other methods for me. It worked like a charm until I was trying to use @Data in such a pojo class.

```
@Data
public class MyPojo {
    private final String name;
    private final int from;
    private final int to;
    // other fields
}
```

What I need to do is to restrict values of `from` and `to` when creating this pojo so that `to` will always be greater than `from`, but it seems that in order to achieve this logic, I have to rewrite the constructor all by myself with lots of code similar to `this.name = name`.

PS: I think using `super` from inheritance could be a workaround, but it may make the program harder to be understood.

Is there any better way to satisfy this need?

Answer (score 1):

@Data annotation is not providing any way to validate construction arguments. I feel you need to annotate your pojo with @Getter @Setter @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode annotations and write constructor on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Lombok's website, I don't see any way to restrict constructor parameters to specific values, especially relative to another variable that may have not been initialized yet.  You'll probably have to create a concrete constructor for this class.

> but it may make the program harder to be understood

I really wouldn't worry about that as you're already using Lombok, which would make any big program very confusing when trying to track down a specific field/method.